# Store pointer to map key

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::map<Key,Value> mymap;
(void)mymap[Key(...)]; // create value if not there
typename std::map<Key,Value>::iterator it = mymap.find(key);
it->second.pkey = &it->first; // store a pointer to the actual key
```

Is this safe? In other words, is map allowed to copy the key around during insert/erase operations, which would invalidate `Value::pkey`?

Any C++98 vs C++11 differences on this?

Comment: Might be beneficial to store the key in `Value` and use a pointer _to_ the key _as_ the key with a custom compare. Depends on your usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` iterators are only invalidated on erasure (`erase` or `clear`). Inserting new elements into the map doesn't affect existing iterators. This is the same in C++98 and C++11.

If an iterator remains valid it follows that the key it points to also remains valid.